# Decoder does not accept Output of Bidirectional Encoder

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, bidirectional, seq2seq, attention-model

I'm trying to implement a Encoder Decoder Model with Tensorflow. The Encoder is a bidirectional cell.

```
def encoder(hidden_units, encoder_embedding, sequence_length):
    forward_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_units)
    backward_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_units)

    bi_outputs, final_states = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(forward_cell, backward_cell, encoder_embedding, sequence_length= sequence_length, dtype=tf.float32)
    encoder_outputs = tf.concat(bi_outputs, 2)
    forward_cell_state, backward_cell_state =final_states
    cell_state_final = tf.concat([forward_cell_state.c, backward_cell_state.c],1)
    hidden_state_final = tf.concat([forward_cell_state.h, backward_cell_state.h],1)
    encoder_final_state = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(c=cell_state_final, h=hidden_state_final)

    return encoder_outputs, encoder_final_state
```

Something went wrong between Encoder and Decoder. I get an Error like ValueError: Shapes (?, 42) and (12, 21) are not compatible ....

The Decoder has a attention mechanism and looks like this:

```
def decoder(decoder_embedding, vocab_size, hidden_units, sequence_length, encoder_output, encoder_state, batchsize):
    projection_layer = Dense(vocab_size)
    helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(decoder_embedding, sequence_length=sequence_length)

    # Decoder
    decoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_units)

    # Attention Mechanis
    attention_mechanism = tf.contrib.seq2seq.LuongAttention(hidden_units, encoder_output)
    attn_cell = tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(decoder_cell, attention_mechanism, attention_layer_size=hidden_units)
    # Initial attention
    attn_zero = attn_cell.zero_state(batch_size=batchsize, dtype=tf.float32)
    ini_state = attn_zero.clone(cell_state=encoder_state)

    decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(cell=attn_cell, initial_state=ini_state, helper=helper, output_layer=projection_layer)
    decoder_outputs, _final_state, _final_sequence_lengths = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder)

    return decoder_outputs
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the number of hidden units of the encoder is twice as large as of the decoder and you are trying to Luong-style attention. It computes the attention energies (state similarities) as a dot-products between the decoder state and all encoder states—and the dot product requires the same dimensionality.

You have several options:

1. Use Bahdanau-style attention that has an additional non-linear layer into a shared encoder-decoder space.
2. Change the dimensionality of your encoder or decoder such that the hidden states will be the same, i.e. encoder's `hidden_units` = 2 × decoder's `hidden_units`
3. Add a linear dense layer after the encoder output that would project the encoder outputs to the decoder's hidden dimension.